# Disable <input type="file"> passing its content

Tags: html, laravel, input, upload, input-type-file

I have a `<form>` with many fields and an `<input type="file">` in it. Each field should enable the next one and prevent the user from rolling back, unless the user click cancel button and start again from the beginning. Like in this scheme:

```
input 1 -> ENABLE
input 2 -> disable
input 3 (type="file") -> disable
input 4 -> disable
```

and after selection:

```
input 1 -> disable
input 2 -> ENABLE
input 3 (type="file") -> disable
input 4 -> disable
```

The problem is when the user choose a file to upload in input 3 above, this field should become `disabled` or `readonly`, but if disabled, no file is passed to my controller when submitting the form and if readonly it seem the field is still actually selectable and working.

Is there a way to block the `<input type="file">` and to pass its value to my controller?

Comment: use CSS to make it looks like disabled. Otherwise, that is the default HTML form behaviour.

Comment: @AnujShrestha mmm.... good point, do you know how can i prevent the user from interacting to "bycssfakedisabled" input?

Comment: I am not good with CSS so I cannot help you in that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way comes to my mind without changing your upload method is hiding file input once its selected but i dont think thats a good idea since user may have choosen wrong file.

I'd suggest do the upload via ajax or with a button trigger when its selected, get uploaded path and store it into a hidden input after that hide file input and may be show uploaded file preview (image or filename etc.)

Comment: as long as I know, you can not pass file to hidden input... Am I wrong?

Comment: No you are not wrong. You can not pass file to hidden but you can pass upload result if you upload right after selection. Thats what i've suggested